# window crash and partial rendering in opengl

Tags: python, opengl, glut, pyopengl

When executed not all lines are printed on the window. Moreover the window crashes after glutSwapBuffers() in function showScreen. Here's an image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuFch.jpg

```
w, h, g = 1200, 900, 1

def plot(coordinates, stringa, g, Px, Px1):
    x, y = coordinates
    while Px >= Px1:
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        if stringa[Px] == "A":
            glVertex2f(x, y)
            glVertex2f(x, y - g)
            y -= g
        elif stringa[Px] == "B":
            glVertex2f(x, y)
            glVertex2f(x + g, y)
            x += g
        elif stringa[Px] == "C":
            glVertex2f(x, y)
            glVertex2f(x, y + g)
            y += g
        elif stringa[Px] == "D":
            glVertex2f(x, y)
            glVertex2f(x - g, y)
            x -= g
        glEnd()
        Px -= 1

def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def showScreen(coordinates, stringa, g, Px, Px1):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    iterate()
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 3.0)
    plot(coordinates, stringa, g, Px, Px1)
    glutSwapBuffers()
    time.sleep(5)

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE |GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(w, h)
window = glutCreateWindow("dragon curve in Opengl")
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen([300, 400], stringa, x, len(stringa)-1, 0))
glutIdleFunc(showScreen([300, 400], stringa, x, len(stringa)-1, 0)) 
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Terminated in {round(end - start, 2)} seconds')
glutMainLoop()
```

I get this error in the function showScreen after glutSwapBuffers()

```
freeglut (foo): Fatal error in program.  NULL display callback not permitted in GLUT 3.0+ or freeglut 2.0.1+
```

What does this error mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you called `glutDisplayFunc` but did not provide a function as the first argument.

I know it appears as you did, but take a closer look at this line:

`glutDisplayFunc(showScreen(...))`

Here's what happens:

1. first, `showScreen(...)` is called and returns `None`
2. This value is used as the first argument of glutDisplayFunc: `glutDisplayFunc(None)`
3. An error occurs because glutDisplayFunc expects a function but got `None`

The same error will happen with glutIdleFunc, too.

To fix this for both of them, give glutDisplayFunc and glutIdleFunc *just* the name of the function:

```py
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen)
```

Now there is still a problem, because glut will not provide *any* arguments to `showScreen`. It will run it like this: `showScreen()`.

This is a problem because your showScreen function expects a couple arguments. But it actually needs to be defined with none: `def showScreen():`
That means you will have to provide those variables in another way.

datenwolf is suggesting that you create a new function that accepts no arguments and just runs `showScreen(...)`

```py
def doShowScreen():
  showScreen(showScreen([300, 400], stringa, x, len(stringa)-1, 0))

glutDisplayFunc(doShowScreen)
glutIdleFunc(doShowScreen)
```

Comment: ok, I converted the arguments to global variables, and this fixed the the crash. But still, only some lines are displayed on the window, as shown on the image

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the dragon curve, are you sure your viewport is capturing the whole image? What happens when you expand your viewport to include negative coordinates? (-500,-500, 1000, 1000)

Comment: Thanks I noticed that the the viewport and glOrtho() was not set right, i changed their args to glViewport(0, 0, 1200, 900) (for the resolution) and glOrtho(0.0, 1200, 0.0, 900, 0.0, 1.0) quite the same.

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty much telling you what the problem is. You didn't supply a display function. This is what you wrote:

```
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen([300, 400], stringa, x, len(stringa)-1, 0))
```

What this does is, that it calls the function `showScreen`, and what is returned from this call is then passed to `glutDisplayFunction`. Your `showScreen` function doesn't return anything.

This is not what you want. You must either use a `lambda` to capture the parameters to show screen, or use a helper function. E.g. this

```
glutDisplayFunc(lambda: showScreen([300, 400], stringa, x, len(stringa)-1, 0))
```

*However given the fact that you're passing in the viewport and other parameters to showScreen it is very unlikely, that this really what you want!*